# Confusing between Native and Managed in CPP/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli

If i use /clr mode to compile a code that has somthing like the following:

```
int x = 3;
char ch='A';
int arr[]="Hi";
array<int>^ ManArr1={44};
array<int>^ ManArr2= gcnew array<int> {44};
```

my questions now:
Would the type `int` be mapped to `System::Int32` ?? and what about `char ch` ? Are they considerd as native or managed type? Where will be executed! through MSIL or not!!

We see that `int arr[]` is a native array, does that mean it will be executed out of MSIL?

The last question  ,, For both the managed array `ManArr1` & `ManArr2` what is the difference between the two initialization ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When compiling with `/clr`, your entire program is converted to MSIL unless you use `#pragma managed(off)` or `#pragma unmanaged`

- `int` is equivalent to `System::Int32`
- `char` is equivalent to `System::SByte` (not `System::Char`!)
- Both of these types are "primitive". Managed code sees them as managed types and native code sees native types.
- Native arrays will use unverifiable MSIL (same as C# pointers, for example)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding `"For both the managed array ManArr1 & ManArr2 what is the difference between the two initialization ??"`

There is no functional difference, one is a shorthand for the other.